# subtract values from one column SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, subtraction

I have problem. I have a table with three columns (User,Value, Date). Something like this:

```
User    VALUE   DATE

U1      23      30-07-2015
U2      47      30-07-2015
U3      43      30-07-2015
U1      21      29-07-2015
U2      22      29-07-2015
U3      56      29-07-2015
```

I would like to subtract values from column Value in this way :

23-21 ;47-22 ;43-56 ;

(the same User but different Date)

I dont know how I can do this... help me, please! :)

Comment: Can you be a little more specific, e.g. do you always want to subtract the older value from the newer for each user? Can there be more than two dates for a given user and, if so, what results do you expect? What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: yes, I want to subtract the older value from the newer - always :) and for each user - always :) . and for example: I have dates in table: 25.04, 31.04, 03.05, 17.05 I subtract values from 17.05 and 03.05. ( so we subtract older value from the newest)

Comment: That still doesn't quite answer what happens if you have more than 2 dates for a given user.  And what about user `U3` in your sample data?  How would I know to do `43-56` instead of `56-43`?  they both have the same date.

Comment: Yes. I'm sorry I made mistake. there should be 30-07-2015 instead of 29-07-15 (now its okay)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
select T1.value-T2.value from your_table T1
INNER JOIN
your_table T2 ON T1.USER=T2.USER
WHERE T1.date<>T2.date
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
with cte as
(
select RN=row_number() over(partition by user order by [date] desc),
[User],
VALUE
from yourtable
)
select  [User],
        DIFF=MAX(case when rn= 1 then VALUE end)-MAX(case when rn= 2 then VALUE end)
from cte
Group by [user]
```